# Using Jquery load method with Slick plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create an HTML page (index.html) using loaded divs from a second HTML sheet (b.html). I would like the loaded content to be displayed in a carousel using the Jquery Slick plugin. I'm using the following code to load the content and then put it into a carousel:

In index.html

```
<div id='includedContent' class='slides'></div>
```

In the code.js file

```
$("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
$('.slides').slick();
```

The divs appear one after another in the page but not in a carousel. If I include the divs directly in the index HTML file (index.html) and simply call  the slick plugin using: `$('.slides').slick();` it works fine.

Is 'loaded' content treated in a different way?
Very new to JavaScript, all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait to load the content, only after loading content initialize the plugin. So move the code inside success callback function of **[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**. In your code `$('.slides')` selector will not get any element , since it's not loaded yet.

```
$("#includedContent").load("b.html",function(){
   $('.slides').slick();
});
```

Comment: Wow thanks, feel like I've fallen through a trapdoor to a whole new world of understanding. I'd not come across this idea of asynchronous programming in any of the tutorials I've been following.

Answer (score 0):

Just load the content and call the `.slick()` loader.

```
$("#includedContent").load("b.html", function () {
  $('.slides').slick();
});
```

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes the second argument to be the function that executes after loading the content. So that `.slick()`, gets executed on the existing content. You **cannot** delegate like events, so use the `success` callback.